# Change buffer size of named pipe

Tags: fifo

I hear that for named pipes, writes that are smaller than about 512bytes are atomic (the writes won't interleave).

Is there a way to increase that amount for a specific named pipe?

something like:

```
mkfifo mynamedpipe --buf=2500
```

Supposedly this is the full documentation:
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mkfifo-invocation.html#mkfifo-invocation

`man mkfifo` takes me to that page.

Comment: also wondering how to lookup the buffer size on a given platform, not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `fifo` file is just a type of file which when opened for both reading and writing instantiates a pipe like a pipe() system call would.

On Linux at least, the data that transits though that pipe is not stored on the file system at all (only in the kernel as kernel memory). And the *size* attribute of the fifo file is not relevant and is always 0.

On Linux, you can change the size of a pipe buffer (whether that pipe has been instantiated with `pipe()` or via opening a fifo file) with the `F_SETPIPE_SZ` `fcntl()`, though for unprivileged users, that's bound by `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`. Any of the writer or reader to the pipe can issue that `fcntl()` though it makes more sense for the writer to do it. In the case of a named pipe, you'd need to do that for each pipe instantiated though the fifo file.

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ exec 3<> fifo # instantiate the pipe
$ seq 20000 > fifo
^C  # seq hangs because it's trying to write more than 64KiB
$ exec 3<&- 3<> fifo # close the first pipe and instantiate a new one
$ (perl -MFcntl -e 'fcntl(STDOUT, 1031, 1048576)'; seq 20000) > fifo
$ # went through this time
```

Above, I used `perl` to issue the `fcntl()`, harcoding the value of `F_SETPIPE_SZ` (1031 on my system).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing `F_SETPIPE_SZ`, there is a bash shell implementation that have the same effect, replacing the expression `fifo` by a substitution of processus like this : `>(stdbuf -o100M grep -a '^' > fifo)` (it will be substituted at runtime by the file descriptor `/dev/fd/63`)

```
mkfifo fifo
exec 3<> fifo
seq 12000000 > >(stdbuf -o100M grep -a '^' > fifo)
```

Not all filters are sensitive to changing buffering mode by `stdbuf`, you could not simply use `cat` for example. For the same reason you cannot either say `stdbuf -o100M seq 12000000 > fifo`. As far as I know, classical `sed` `grep` or `awk` do it.

The drawback of this is to mobilize one more process ; the advantage is that you are free to implement a huge buffer size.

Comment: Note that `>(...)` is not specific to nor does it originate in bash. It's from the Korn shell in the mid 80 and is also found in zsh. The same or equivalent feature with different syntax is also found in a few other shells (rc and derivatives, fish, yash).

Comment: Here it relies on the fact that  bash is not waiting for the process started for the substitution. Because it is otherwise generally not desirable (as that means that in `cmd1  >(cmd2 > file); cmd3 file`, `cmd3` may be started before `cmd2` has finished generating `file` for instance), it might change in the future.

Comment: see `pv -qB 100M` for a more straightforward and efficient way to buffer those 100M worth of data in memory (+ 2 pipe buffers)